# I can't get the big file and post message, When I deloy django and vue in the server

Tags: django

1.I deloy the django and the vue to the server
2.When I upload a small file and post message, I can get the message and file; But when i upload a big file and post message, I can get the message is None and can't get the file.
3.This is my django source code.

````py
image_vul_name = request.POST.get("image_vul_name")
    image_vul_port = request.POST.get("image_vul_port")
    image_vul_rank = request.POST.get("image_vul_rank")
    image_vul_rank = float(image_vul_rank)
    image_vul_desc = request.POST.get("image_vul_desc")
    image_vul_lable = request.POST.get("image_vul_lable")
    docker_name = request.FILES['myfile']
    image_name = docker_name.name[:-4]```
````

Comment: does your server config has file limit set? if not what is the default setting? i think you should debug the django function in the view

Comment: server config not set file limit config! I test the django on my ubuntu. Don't have any problems! So, I am confused！

Comment: success! Time prophet is set on the front end！